# Binary Search Tree having issues with recognising when making root node

Tags: java, binary-search-tree

Trying to make a root in this BST as such:

```
if (currentNode == null) {
            currentNode = new BinaryNode(newInt);
            System.out.println(currentNode);
            System.out.println(newInt);
            //System.out.println(newInt.getValue());
            System.out.println("Node Null, made root");
         }else{
```

The println is there for debugging. However I'm having issues as this is the output:

```
BinaryNode@7004ba66
4
Node Null, made root
BinaryNode@4669b7fe
6
Node Null, made root
BinaryNode@46aea8cf
1
Node Null, made root
BinaryNode@74ccd249
3
Node Null, made root
BinaryNode@3301f287
2
Node Null, made root
BinaryNode@44d9973a
8
Node Null, made root
BinaryNode@29578426
7  
Node Null, made root
BinaryNode@30a4effe
5
Node Null, made root
BinaryNode@1c8825a5
9
Node Null, made root
```

Which makes me think it isn't recognising (currentNode == null) like it should. Any ideas why?

full pastebin: [here](http://pastebin.com/v43SrSyL)

Any help greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that when you assign `currentNode`, `root` does not get assigned.

Java passes variables by value, meaning that a copy of the value or a reference gets passed into your method. In this case, `currentNode`, a formal parameter of your `insertNode` method, is passed a copy of the `root` field returned by the `getRoot` method.

To fix this, you should split the `insertNode` method in two:

```
public void insert(int newInt);
```

and

```
private BinaryNode insert(int newInt, BinaryNode node);
```

The public method should be used without `getRoot` parameter (the users of your class inserting in the tree should never need to pass the root, otherwise they would be able to break your tree by passing a node in the middle with numbers that should go in a different branch).

The private method should return the old or the new node. You should be using it like this:

```
public void insert(int newInt) {
    root = insert(newInt, root);
}
```

The method itself should return new node if `node` passed in is `null`. When `node` is not null, the method should return the node passed in.

As far as the `outputList` problem goes, you should use `StringBuffer` instead of `String` to construct the output. Unlike `String` which is immutable, `StringBuilder` is mutable. It lets you change the string inside it (use `append` instead of `+=`).

Comment: Thank you, just assigned currentNode as root, and it worked. The main output line as seen in the pastebin isn't working though - can you spot any glaring errors? Ty!

Comment: @Sphyxx same problem: strings are passed by value, so assigning to `outString` has no effect for the caller. Easiest solution is to `return outString`.

Answer (score 1):

You are not assigning to the root of your tree. Change it to:

```
if (root== null) {
        root= new BinaryNode(newInt);
```